# How to simplify e to power of j.t

Tags: mathematics

I have exam tommorow and cant get this figured out :( dont blame me but please answer this question. I Want to simplify this term:

3 times ((e topowerof 5jt) + (e topowerof -5jt))

Thanks.

Comment: For future reference we have the MathJax LaTeX rendering engine active on the site so that you could write `$3 e^{5jt} e^{-5jt}$` and get $3 e^{5jt} e^{-5jt}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$6\cos(5t)$; use Euler's formula for sine and cosine.

$\exp(i*\theta)=cos(\theta)+i*sin(\theta)$

From this you can show, 
$$sin(\theta)=(1/2i)*(\exp(i*\theta)-\exp(-i*\theta))$$
$$cos(\theta)=(1/2)*(\exp(i*\theta)+\exp(-i*\theta))$$

Comment: Thanks, I know the answer is 2sin(3t) as it is on my teachers handout...can you please say how to get to this number? what steps should be done? I know eulers formulas but cant apply it here.

Comment: It's not $2\sin(3t)$; it's what New Horizon said.